# Opening Maxmind db in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, maxmind

I am trying to open maxmind opensource database in my nodejs application. My application recieves a list of ip addressses from a java application. Application then returns the latitude and longitude corresponding to each ip. I have succesfully done this synchronously, but i want to do it asynchronously to make things a little faster. I have written a code for this, but the application gets killed everytime. I am guessing that the reason might be simultaneous opening of the same database(I might be wrong :D). I am posting the code below. Please take a look at it and make some suggestions on where I am going wrong. Thanks!!!

```
app.post('/endPoint', function(req, res){
var obj = req.body;
var list = [];
var ipList = obj.ipList;
for(var i = 0; i<ipList.length; i++){
var ip = ipList[i];
//console.log(i);
maxmind.open('./GeoLite2-City.mmdb', function(err, cityLookup){
if(err) throw err;
console.log("open database");
var city = cityLookup.get(ip);
if(city!=null){
var cordinates = {'latitude': city.location.latitude, 'longitude': geodata.location.longitude};
        //console.log(cordinates);
        list.push(cordinates);
      }
      if(list.length == ipList.length){
        res.json({finalMap: list});
      }
});
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should open the database only once, and reuse it.

The easiest solution would be to *synchronously* open the database at the top of your file:

```
const maxmind    = require('maxmind');
const cityLookup = maxmind.openSync('./GeoLite2-City.mmdb');
```

Reading it asynchronously wouldn't speed things up a whole lot, and because loading the database is done only once (during app startup), I don't think it's a big deal that it may temporarily block the event loop for a few seconds.

And use the `cityLookup` function in your request handler:

```
app.post('/endPoint', function(req, res) {
  ...
  let city = cityLookup.get(ip);
  ...
});
```

Comment: Hey!! thanks for the answer. It really worked faster by opening the database a single time.!!

Comment: Want to go even faster?? Uninstall maxmind and just load the binary mmdblookup program in linux.  Then have nodeJS simply run the console command with ip address.

Load maxmindlib into your linux console and take the load off of your web app.

https://github.com/runk/node-maxmind/wiki/Most-Efficient-Integration-Methods

Comment: @indospace.io I hope you're not suggesting to spawn a command line utility for each request? Because performance for that would be pretty horrible (even if the CLI utility itself would be fast). Last time I used Maxmind databases, I used [`mmdb-reader`](https://github.com/gosquared/mmdb-reader), which reads the entire database into memory. Very fast, but does require a fair bit of RAM.