# Opening maxmind DB and accessing it in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, maxmind

Previously I was using like this:

[Opening Maxmind db in Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44039625/opening-maxmind-db-in-nodejs)

Now, updated the modules as per `node 10`.
So, need help to integrate it.

[reference](https://github.com/runk/node-maxmind)

```
const maxmind = require('maxmind');
exports.getIsoCountry = function(pIpAddress) {

  modules.debugLog('inside getIsoCountry : ',pIpAddress);

  maxmind.open(sGlAppVariable.maxmindDbPath)
  .then(function(lookup) {
    var ipData = lookup.get(pIpAddress);
    //console.log(ipData);
    console.log('iso_code',ipData.country.iso_code);
    return ipData.country.iso_code;
  });

}
```

`console.log(getIsoCountry('66.6.44.4'));` it should print country code. but it is `undefined` always. because this is a promise.

How to call this `getIsoCountry` function?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for execution to complete, for that, you should use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Modify your code as below, then it should work:

```
const maxmind = require('maxmind');
exports.getIsoCountry = function(pIpAddress) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    modules.debugLog('inside getIsoCountry : ',pIpAddress);
      maxmind.open(sGlAppVariable.maxmindDbPath)
      .then(function(lookup) {
        var ipData = lookup.get(pIpAddress);
        console.log('iso_code',ipData.country.iso_code);
        resolve(ipData.country.iso_code);
      });
  });
}

getIsoCountry("66.6.44.4").then((rData) => {
  console.log(rData)
});
```

**Below is sample code:**

```js
var getIsoCountry = function(pIpAddress) {

  return maxmind().then(function() {
       return "Code for IP: " + pIpAddress;
    });

  function maxmind() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve("done")
    });
  }

}

getIsoCountry("1.1.1.1").then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
});
```